# Failed prop type: `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have looked up all the answers for this specific case, however all of them either suggest that one is not extending from React.Component, or in other cases suggesting that having named exports instead of default exports  and importing classes with curly braces rather than without might be the problem.

**The Error:**

Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`.

I've updated all my dependancies, checked for all these cases and still can't figure out why the error is thrown.

Below is my code:

**App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Redirect, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
// components
import NotFound from '../common/NotFound';
import Home from './home/Home';
import About from './about/About';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          render={() => (
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path={'/'} component={Home} />
              <Route exact path={'/about'} component={About} />
              <Route render={() => <Redirect to={'/'} />} />
              <Route component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
          )}
        />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

**About.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
// style
import classes from './About.scss';

export default function About() {
  return <div className={classes.aboutContainer}>Hello</div>;
}
```

**Home.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
// components
import NavigationFull from '../navigation/NavigationFull';
import NavigationToggle from '../navigation/NavigationToggle';
import About from '../about/About';
// styles
import classes from './Home.scss';
import fullNavClass from '../navigation/NavigationFull.scss';

export default function Home() {
  const navigation = useRef(null);
  const [topOffset, setTopOffset] = useState(window.innerHeight);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleStickyHeader);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleStickyHeader);
    };
  }, []);

  function handleStickyHeader() {
    const { offsetTop, clientHeight, classList } = navigation.current;

    setTopOffset(offsetTop);
    // 15px added to substitute for the lack of margin.
    const offset = window.pageYOffset + clientHeight + 15;

    if (offset > topOffset) {
      classList.add(fullNavClass.fixed);
    } else {
      classList.remove(fullNavClass.fixed);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <NavigationToggle />
      <NavigationFull reference={navigation} color={'white'} />
      <div className={classes.introContainer}>
        <span className={classes.job}>SOFTWARE ENGINEER & UX DESIGNER</span>
        <div className={classes.about}>
          <span className={classes.welcome}>Hey, I'm</span>
          <span className={classes.name}>Filip Grebowski</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <About />
    </>
  );
}
```

The error is thrown in the place where the `<About />` component is initiated.

Any ideas?

Comment: it's not about component , it's something different please check your code here https://codesandbox.io/s/98o5jr8xmr

Comment: That's interesting, thank you. I will look into this.

Comment: please add remanining component in codesandbox so I will look into it

Comment: @DhavalPatel https://codesandbox.io/s/mmlvooq63y :-) Thanks.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/rjr32r05om it's working

Answer (score 0):

When using aliased imports, it can try to import `example.scss`, instead of `example.js`. Instead, you can either use declarative extensions when supporting files reside within the same directory path:

```
import NotFound from '../common/NotFound.js';
import Home from './home/Home.js';
import About from './about/About.js';
```

or, an alternative would be to separate your supporting files into their own folder:

```
└── components
    ├── About
    |   ├── __tests__
    |   |   └── about.test.js
    |   ├── styles
    |   |   └── about.scss
    |   └── about.js
    |
    ├── Home
    |   ├── __tests__
    |   |   └── home.test.js
    |   ├── styles
    |   |   └── home.scss
    |   └── home.js
    |
    ├── NotFound
    |   ├── __tests__
    |   |   └── notfound.test.js
    |   ├── styles
    |   |   └── notfound.scss
    |   └── notfound.js
    |
    ...etc
```

Also, you can simplify your `About` function export like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { aboutContainer } from './About.scss';

export default () => <div className={aboutContainer}>Hello</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import React from 'react';
// style
import classes from './About.scss';

const About = () => {
  return <div className={classes.aboutContainer}>Hello</div>;
}

export default About;
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not fix the issue.